# How can i grant an execute statment

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to grant TRIGGERS, FUNCTIONS and PROCEDURES to a role. I have the code to do it with procedure but with triggers and functions it not work.

```
create role Level1;
grant execute any trigger to Level1;
grant execute any procedure to Level1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User owns tables, functions and procedures. That user created a role and wanted to grant execute on various objects to the role.

- for triggers, it doesn't make sense - they fire upon certain action on the table they are created on. Therefore, you'd grant privileges on the table, not on the trigger
- for functions and procedures, you'd grant execute privilege on exact functions and procedures (not for *all of them* in a single statement), e.g.

  ```
  grant execute on p_insert_student to level1;
  grant execute on f_average_marks  to level1;
  ```

What you posted (`grant execute any procedure`) is a system privilege; that's kind of *dangerous*; are you sure you want to let `level1` execute absolutely any procedure within the database?

Also, there's no separate grant for functions; in this context, they are considered to be *procedures* so `execute any procedure` affects functions as well.

Comment: Yes is a test for university, but how can i get te privilage to execute triggers to any table for a role not for a user

Comment: I told you - there's no privilege to execute a trigger. You'd grant privileges on a **table**.

Comment: Specifically, you would grant insert, update, or delete privileges on the table. The only way to execute a trigger is to modify the _data_ in the table in such a way that it causes ("triggers") the trigger to execute automatically.